# AFNetworking restore HTTP operation after connection lost

Tags: http, connection, afnetworking

I'd like to ask if AFNetworking library offers some kind of support at automatic restore of http operation when they can't be finished because of connection loss.

As an example I'd like to enqueue more http post operation, each one used to upload one image: how can I manage the situation in which the connection is lost (I'd like to know if there are any code that will restart unfinished operation when connection will be available)?

```
    NSURL *remoteUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:UPLOAD_SERVER_URL];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:remoteUrl];
[httpClient setParameterEncoding: AFJSONParameterEncoding];
[httpClient setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
    NSLog(@"Conenction lost...");
}];
NSMutableURLRequest *afRequest = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" 
                                                                       path:@"/upload/" 
                                                                 parameters:[photoBean asDictWithoutImageData]
                                                  constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) 
                                  {                                    
                                      [[photoBean asDict] enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
                                          if ([key isEqualToString:@"media"])
                                          {
                                              [formData appendPartWithFileData: obj name:@"media" fileName:photoBean._imageFile mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
                                          }

                                      }];

                                  }
                                  ];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:afRequest];
[operation setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"%@", operation.responseString); //Gives a very scary warning
}];

[operation start];
```

Thanks!